# Executing a function in parallel to process huge XML files in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe filedf which has only 1 column (filename) and many rows. These are filenames of the XML files with size>= 1GB. There is another function as below.

```
def transformfiles(filename):
  ordered_dict = xmltodict.parse(filename)
  <do process 1>
  <do process 2>
```

I want to call the function transformfiles on all the rows of the dataframe filedf concurrently.

Currently I am using a for loop to loop through all the rows in the dataframe and call this function which only runs sequentially.

```
filename=filedf.select(filenames).collect()
filelist=[r['filename'] for r in [filenames]
for fname in filelist:
  transformfiles(fname)
```

I have also tried the udf approach of wrapping the function in a udf and then using it in withColumn like below.

```
def transformfiles(filename):
  ordered_dict = xmltodict.parse(filename)
  <do process 1>
  <do process 2>
return "Success"
transform_udf=udf(lambda x:transformfiles(x), StringType())
df2=filedf.withColumn("process_status",transform_udf("filename"))
```

Both these approaches runs in the same time.

I am running 140 GB mem, 20 core cluster with 17 workers.

Please let me know if there is an approach to bring about parallelism while doing this. I am not sure if the approach I am using utilizes the cluster resources efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you built that dataframe with the filenames, it can be that it consists of just one partition. And as Spark parallelizes on partition level, then indeed the udf version would still basically go sequentially over all the data.

You must make sure that you partition your dataframe into multiple partitions, and then those partitions can be handled in parallel by multiple executors/workers.

Use something like [filedf.repartition(numPartitions, "filename")](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition) to ensure your data is distributed over multiple partitions. For the number of partitions, that depends on various things, like how much resources an executor would need to parse such an XML file (and so how many concurrent parsing jobs you can have running on your cluster), things like possible data skew, etc. You could always start out with e.g. the default value of 200 to see the effect and start tuning.

An additional remark: Your dataframe contains just the filename, and you do not return actual parsed data from the UDF. So, apparently your `transformfile` function takes care of actually getting the file content, and writing/handling the parsed data somewhere (so you want to use Spark mainly for easy parallelization, not really for data processing?). Ensure that you don't have any bottlenecks in those parts either (for example if 200 Spark executors would start concurrently writing to a single external destination and overload it).

Comment: tijmen, yes the transformfile function takes care of the writing the parsed and processed data. So basically if I write the finalname df as parquet files with repartition and then attempt to read it, it should theoretically result in better parallelism.

Comment: I don't think you need to write it first and read it back in, the repartition itself should already do the trick.